# How to add multiple types of fields properly inside a custom made field in CMB2?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, cmb2

I have created a custom field type in CMB2. But I can't add fields properly inside that custom field.
For example, when I try to use a colorpicker field, the default color picker field provided by WordPress is not showing.
I want it to be exactly the same as the default color picker field. Same for the upload field. I want to add a default upload field inside my custom made the field.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj8pt.png)
Any suggestions about how to do this would be great.